# Deploying Django project on Window server with Nginx and Waitress issue

Tags: python, django, nginx, waitress

I followed all of the instructions from here:

[deploy Django with nginx + Waitress](https://github.com/Johnnyboycurtis/webproject#nginx-and-waitress)

All things were going fine, the Django project was successfully deployed.

But the problem that I faced was after I close the cmd of the running script of waitress (runserver.py):

```
#runserver.py
from waitress import serve

from webproject.wsgi import application
# documentation: https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/waitress/en/stable/api.html

if __name__ == '__main__':
    serve(application, host = 'localhost', port='8080')
```

the website stopped working immediately.

After I run the runserver.py from cmd again, the website was back to work but stopped if I close my cmd again.

How do I keep my website alive without the cmd to running waitress?